# What does "gut over" mean?

Tags: meaning, verbs, prepositions

What does "gutted over" mean in Javad Zarif's [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/JZarif/status/399964066472407040)?

> Mr.Secretary, was it Iran that gutted over half of US draft Thursday night? and publicly commented against it Friday morning?

Comment: Could it be that *over half* is a quantity, and the verb is simply *gutted*? (" ... Iran that gutted 51% of ... ")

Comment: I am not sure, what would it mean in that case?

Comment: No idea; have a look at [**gut** *verb* sense 2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gut). It would help if you edited the question to include a link to the source, and made sure that it was exactly accurate.

Comment: Thank you, it is the link:https://twitter.com/JZarif/status/399964066472407040

Comment: Kerry says allies agreed on Iran nuclear deal, Iranians balked. I think Zarif (Iranian Foreign Minister) is answering John Kerry and says it wasn't Iran. (Some say it was France.)

Comment: It would probably be helpful to **edit your question** to include more background, then. What "draft" is he talking about? It could mean "filleted", to "remove the innards of" more than half of a draft document ([**gut** *verb* sense 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gut)), but there isn't enough context in the question.

Comment: My impression: Zarif is responding to an attack or insinuation that Iran is uncooperative. This is a rhetorical question pointing out that somebody **else** gutted the draft, with “gutted” and “over half” as Andrew Leach suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction, given that Iran and the US are currently negotiating, was that Iran had effectively destroyed an American draft proposal by disagreeing with or insisting on the removal of more than half of the wording, to much the same effect as when a cook guts a fish.

Comment: Are they? I'm sorry, I'm British and haven't recently been able to catch up. According to what you say is happening, that would be the most reasonable answer. Upvote.

Comment: I think you're close to the mark, but based on other comments and answers, it sounds like the Iranian minister is using a sarcastic rhetorical question to accuse France of gutting the deal.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Zarif's tweet: "Mr.Secretary, was it Iran that gutted over half of US draft Thursday night?"
Gut[=to destroy the interior of] over half of US draft... [= more than half of...]

Answer (score 1):

To extract essential or major parts of: gut a manuscript.

Comment: Always cite your sources to support your answer. You could earn reps.

Answer (score 0):

In this tweet Mr. Zarif is talking about France part that didn't accept the whole deal between Iran and P5+1. PM of France was against the part of deal and talk against it publicly of one of French radio. Mr. Kerry said that P5+1 was united but Mr. Zarif respond to it that the difference was between yourself not Iran and P5+1.

In my opinion "Gutted over" in this tweet means more like "being not agree with" or "not being interest".

Comment: The background about France's opposition is helpful, but the conclusion about _gutted_ and _over_ is incorrect. It means that France rejected most (“over half”) of the draft proposal, “gutting” it (like a fish).

Answer (score 0):

**[gut](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/GUT)** *tr. v*

> **4**. To reduce or destroy the effectiveness of: *A stipulation added at the last minute gutted the ordinance.*

To render a document ineffective.

Answer (score -1):

This probably means that they toiled over it. Maybe Iran was looking at a US draft to find problems in it and they toiled over half of it on Thursday Night.